# Convert from long to wide format counting frequency of eliminated factor level (Prepping dataframe for input into iNEXT Online)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
df<- data.frame(region= c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2"),loc=c("104","104","104","105","106","107","108", "109", "110", "110", "111"), interact= c("A_B", "B_C", "A_B", "B_C", "B_C", "A_B", "G_H", "I_J", "J_K", "L_M", "M_O"))
```

And I would like to change it from long to wide format so that the region number becomes the variable (column headings) and the rows become counts of the levels of `interact` occurring in that region. The caveat is I would also like the first row to be a count of unique `loc` levels in that region. I will first illustrate the intermediate df:

```
df2<- data.frame(interact= c("", "A_B", "B_C", "G_H", "I_J", "J_K", 
 "L_M", "M_O"), region1= c("3", "2", "3", "0","0","0","0","0"), 
 region2= c("5", "1", "0", "1","1","1","1","1"))
```

You'll notice that there were 3 unique levels in `loc` for region 1 and 5 unique levles in `loc` for region2; thus the first row of numbers indicate the unique `loc` count in that region. All rows to follow represent the frequency of each interaction type among all loc in that region. However, I do not want this `interact` column in the final dataframe so the final output should look like:

```
output<- data.frame(region1= c("3", "2", "3", "0","0","0","0","0"), 
region2= c("5", "1", "0", "1","1","1","1","1"))
```

I have tried the following, but I get stuck adding a row with counts of unique `loc` in each region and I know my current steps are not the most efficient methods:

```
library(tidyr)
df<- df %>% 
group_by(region, interact) %>% 
summarise(freq = n()) 
data_wide <- spread(df, region, freq)
data_wide<- data_wide[,-1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in two steps using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- dcast(setDT(df)[, .(interact = "", uniqueN(loc)), region], 
         interact ~ paste0('region', region))
rbind(d1, dcast(df, interact ~ paste0('region', region), length))
#   interact region1 region2
#1:                3       5
#2:      A_B       2       1
#3:      B_C       3       0
#4:      G_H       0       1
#5:      I_J       0       1
#6:      J_K       0       1
#7:      L_M       0       1
#8:      M_O       0       1
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(df %>%
            group_by(region = paste0('region', region)) %>% 
            summarise(interact = "", V1 = n_distinct(loc)) %>% 
            spread(region, V1),
          df %>% 
            group_by(region = paste0('region', region),
                    interact = as.character(interact)) %>%
            summarise(V1 = n()) %>% 
            spread(region, V1, fill = 0))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  interact region1 region2
#     <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1                3       5
#2      A_B       2       1
#3      B_C       3       0
#4      G_H       0       1
#5      I_J       0       1
#6      J_K       0       1
#7      L_M       0       1
#8      M_O       0       1
```