# Change dataframe in sample by sampling unit format to incidence-frequency format (Prep dataframe for iNext incidence dataframe)

Tags: r, inext

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df<- data.frame(region = c("1","1","1","1","1","2","3","3","3"),
                loc = c("104","104","104","105","105","106","107", "108", "109"), 
                interact = c("A_B","A_B", "B_C", "C_D", "A_B", "E_F", "E_F", "F_G", "A_B"))
```

I would like to make a dataframe that:

1) counts the incidence frequency of a given interaction occurring among `loc` levels for each `region` subset. Therefore, in the example above, in region 1 there are two `loc` (104 and 105) that both have the interact `A_B`. Thus, the incidence frequency of `A_B` for region 1 = 2. Duplicate `interact` levels in the same `loc` are not counted. So while A_B occurs 3 times in region 1, it occurs only in two unique `loc`. The incidence frequency counts how many unique `loc` level this `interact` occurs in.

2) The new dataframe should vectorize all possible `interact` levels among all regions, and count incidences of these for each region. As a consequence,  0's should be included for all levels of interact that did not occur in that region.

3) The first row needs to be a count of unique `loc` levels in that region. In region1 there were 2 loc levels(104,105), region2 1 loc level(106) and  in region 3, 3 loc levels(107-109).

The final output will look like:

```
output<- data.frame(interact = c("","A_B","B_C","C_D","E_F","F_G"),
                    region1 = c("2","2","1","0","1","0"),
                    region2 = c("1","0","0","0","1","0"),
                    region3 = c("3","1","0","0","1","1"))
```

I do not know where to start with this, but here is what I have adapted from @akrun in a similar question posted on [Convert from long to wide format counting frequency of eliminated factor level (Prepping dataframe for input into iNEXT Online)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960473/convert-from-long-to-wide-format-counting-frequency-of-eliminated-factor-level/44961098#44961098), but get errors with:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
 group_by(region = paste0('region', region)) %>% 
        summarise(interact = "", V1 = n_distinct(loc)) %>% 
        spread(region, V1),
      df %>% 
        group_by(region = paste0('region', region) & loc),
                interact = as.character(interact)) %>%
        summarise(V1 = length(unique((interact)) %>% 
        spread(region, V1, fill = 0))
```

Comment: what have you tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: I have added to the OP to address your question. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

With the clarifying comment (and re-reading the question), I'm amending my advice, but it's still using base-R methods. Try this instead:

```
 my_table <- with(df, table(interact, loc, region) )
 apply(my_table, c(1,3), function(x){sum(x > 0)}) 
   # 2nd arg to apply ( 1 & 3) give num of pos "loc"'s by interact and region
```

will give you:

```
        region
interact 1 2 3
     A_B 2 0 1
     B_C 1 0 0
     C_D 1 0 0
     E_F 0 1 1
     F_G 0 0 1
```

If you really need to relabel the region dimension, that's not particularly difficult. This is how I would proceed (assuming you assigned that value to `collapse_tbl`:

```
colnames(collapse_tbl) <- 
           paste0 ("region",  attr( collapse_tbl, 'dimnames')$region)
collapse_tbl
        region
interact region1 region2 region3
     A_B       2       0       1
     B_C       1       0       0
     C_D       1       0       0
     E_F       0       1       1
     F_G       0       0       1
```

That is a matrix-object, rather than a dataframe. And unlike an R 'table'-object, you can use `as.data.frame` if you want it in that class. The "natural" way to handle data is to use the "long" arrangement. You can still use the usual indexing with matrix (or table) objects.

```
> collapse_tbl["F_G", "region3"]
[1] 1
```

The `xtabs` function is often used for this purpose. Both `table` and `xtabs` are in the "original-R-verse".

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, your output sums the A_B interactions occurring within  region 1 to give a total of 3.  I need a count of the number of loc levels it was present in (which would =2). To add some context, instead of getting the total abundance of interactions in a region, I need the number of plots within a region each interaction type occurred in.